# Azure AD B2C - asynchronous email verification

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Using Azure AD B2C with 'Email' specified for the user id.

I've tested the 'Sign up' and 'Sign up v2' user flows in Azure AD B2C. Both of these require the user to verify their email address by sending/entering a verification code. I've enabled MFA for both of these flows, so the mobile number needs to get verified as well.

The product guys have asked if its possible for email verification to be done asynchronously e.g. an email getting sent to the user, but they can verify this (e.g. via a hyperlink in the email) in their own time without having to enter a verification code during the registration process. Is this possible?

FYI. I think the reasoning from the product guys is that MFA via SMS to their mobile is enough. Multiple verifications (i.e. for email AND mobile) is a bit too much in terms of the UX...

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution.

It's possible to disable email verification:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-disable-ev

Can then do and then do external orchestration to send async email. When they click on the link, we can update the verification status via MS Graph API. Don't love this solution, but it's an option...